# How to retrieve storage account key using powershell function app?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-function-app

I'm using powershell function app to retrieve storage account key but i'm not able to access resources .Please help me .

```
$resourceGroup = "DemoResourceGroup"

$AccountName = "Demo"

$Key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $AccountName)

Write-Host "storage account key 1 = " $Key
```

**I'm getting following error :**

2020-05-14T14:00:05Z   [Error]   ERROR: Get-AzStorageAccountKey : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
At D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1:25 char:8
+ $key = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName "DocumentParser_FBI ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzStorageAccountKey], ValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountKeyCommand

Script stack trace:
   at , D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTrigger1\run.ps1: line 25

Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException: 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageAccountsOperations.ListKeysWithHttpMessagesAsync(String resourceGroupName, String accountName, Nullable`1 expand, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageAccountsOperationsExtensions.ListKeysAsync(IStorageAccountsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String accountName, Nullable`1 expand, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.StorageAccountsOperationsExtensions.ListKeys(IStorageAccountsOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String accountName, Nullable`1 expand)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.GetAzureStorageAccountKeyCommand.ExecuteCmdlet()

Comment: Error message clearly indicates that you're not passing the subscription id.

Comment: Thnx for your reply......i tried using  ""Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "SubName" | Select-AzureRmSubscription "" then again i am getting another error

Comment: I think you need to use `Select-AzureSubscription` (not `Select-AzureRmSubscription`) with the new `Az.*` modules

Comment: Thank you very much @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the script you provide, you use `Az` module. So if you want to choose which Azure subscription you use, you need to use the command `Select-AzSubscription`. Besides, you also can add `-Subscription "<subscription Id>"` in `Connect-AzAccoun` to ensure when you login, you choose the right subscription.

For example

1. Create the service principal

```
Import-Module Az.Resources # Imports the PSADPasswordCredential object
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential -Property @{ StartDate=Get-Date; EndDate=Get-Date -Year 2024; Password=<Choose a strong password>}
$sp = New-AzAdServicePrincipal -DisplayName ServicePrincipalName -PasswordCredential $credentials
```

2. assign the role to the service principal. For example, assign Contributor role to the sp at the subscription level

```
New-AzRoleAssignment -ApplicationId <service principal application ID> -RoleDefinitionName "Contributor" `
-Scope "/subscriptions/<subscription id>"
```

3. Script

```
$appId = "your sp app id"
$password = "your sp password"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($appId, $secpasswd)

Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $mycreds -Tenant <you sp tenant id>
Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionName "CSP Azure" | Select-AzSubscription

$resourceGroup = "nora4test"

$AccountName = "qsstorageacc"

$Key = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -Name $AccountName)[0].Value

Write-Host "storage account key 1 = " $Key
```

Comment: I don't think this advice is appropriate, for powershell running in an [Azure Function App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/functions/). For one thing, you don't import modules with Import-Module, you do it with [Dependency Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-powershell?tabs=portal#dependency-management).